# How to define an infinite anti-diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, infinite-matrices

We can define an infinite diagonal matrix with some ease, and then say that a finite diagonal matrix is the top left sub-matrix of our infinite one.

Can we define an infinite anti-diagonal matrix? It seems more like a facet of the indexing system than anything else, but where we can refer to the "top left" term for a matrix of any size, I don't see a way to reference the "bottom left" term, if there is no bottom.

I'll note that we can still say that

```
A[i,j] = A[i-1,j+1]
```

An anti-diagonal matrix of any finite size is trivial to define; does it not exist as an infinite matrix?

Comment: It is not too hard if you index your matrix by $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Hmm do you have an example or a reference?

Comment: If the matrix is indexed by the integers, just have non-zero elements $A_{i,-i}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}$.